# Unit-testing the undefined evaluated in lazy expression in Haskell

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, hspec

Writing a unit test in Haskell where an expression should fail when `undefined` is encountered is a bit tricky. I tried the following with HSpec:

```
module Main where

import Test.Hspec
import Control.Exception (evaluate)

main :: IO ()
main = hspec $ do
  describe "Test" $ do
    it "test case" $ do
      evaluate (take 1 $ map (+1) [undefined, 2, 3]) `shouldThrow` anyException
```

to no avail. It reports me `did not get expected exception: SomeException`

If I evaluate the same expression in REPL, I'd get:

```
[*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at libraries\base\GHC\Err.hs:79:14 in base:GHC.Err
  undefined, called at <interactive>:2:20 in interactive:Ghci1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `evaluate` doesn't force your expression to NH <s>or even WHNF</s><sup>1</sup>. Try `x <- evaluate (take 1 $ map (+1) [undefined, 2, 3])` in GHCi - it doesn't give you any error! The only reason it does when you paste in `evaluate (take 1 $ map (+1) [undefined, 2, 3])` is that GHCi also tries to print the result of what it got and, to do that, it ends up trying to evaluate the expression.

If you want to see how much of a thunk has been evaluated, you can always use `:sprint` in GHCi:

```
ghci> x <- evaluate (take 1 $ map (+1) [undefined, 2, 3])
ghci> :sprint x
x = [_]
```

As you can see, `evaluate` hasn't forced the expression far enough to realize `x` contains an `undefined`. A quick fix is to evaluate the thing you are examining to normal form using `force`.

```
import Test.Hspec
import Control.Exception (evaluate)
import Control.DeepSeq (force)

main :: IO ()
main = hspec $ do
  describe "Test" $ do
    it "test case" $ do
      evaluate (force (take 1 $ map (+1) [undefined, 2, 3] :: [Int])) 
        `shouldThrow` anyException
```

[`force`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq-1.4.2.0/docs/Control-DeepSeq.html#v:force) lets you trigger the evaluation of thunks until the argument is full evaluated. Note that it has an `NFData` (stands for "normal form data") constraint on it, so you may find yourself deriving `Generic` and `NFData` for your data structures.

---

<sup>1</sup> Thanks for @AlexisKing for pointing out that `evaluate` *does* push its argument into WNHF, which is why `head $ map (+1) [undefined, 2, 3]` does trigger the error. In the case of `take`, it isn't enough though.

Comment: This answer is good, but I’m confused when you say that `evaluate` doesn’t evaluate to WHNF when [the docs explicitly state that it evaluates its argument to WHNF](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:evaluate).

Comment: @AlexisKing I stand corrected! In any case, WNHF is not enough, hence why you need `NFData`.

Comment: So, actually, the test passes because it produces a list with a single undefined element? Why isn't the (+1) function applied?

Comment: Since there is no need to inspect the first element of the list, Haskell doesn't bother to try to evaluate `(+1) undefined`. The thunk is there, but Haskell doesn't need to force it for `evaluate`.