# Testing laziness of IsString s => s -> Bool function

Tags: haskell, text, lazy-sequences

Is there any way I can test that a function `p :: IsString s => s -> Bool` evaluates its input lazily? That is, it only consumes a part of its input when determining its result. And is it possible in such a way that it's compatible with both `String` and `Data.Text.Lazy`?

I've looked at the Q&A [Unit-testing the undefined evaluated in lazy expression in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41151927/unit-testing-the-undefined-evaluated-in-lazy-expression-in-haskell), which doesn't cover `IsString` specifically, and I've found the [StrictCheck](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/StrictCheck) package on Hackage that I'm not really sure how works. Does it apply here?

### Problem

I've got a predicate,

```
p :: IsString s => s -> Bool
```

and an Hspec test,

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

...
import Data.String (fromString)

spec_p :: Spec
spec_p =
  describe "p" $
    it "is lazy" $ p (fromString x) `shouldBe` y
      where
        x = "foo" ++ [undefined]
        y = True
```

that fails if `p ("foo" ++ [undefined])` tries to consume any more than `"foo"`.

This works fine for my `String` implementation,

```
import qualified Data.List as L

p :: String -> Bool
p = ("foo" `L.isPrefixOf`)
```

But it does not work so fine on my `Data.Text.Lazy` implementation,

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as T
import           Data.Text.Lazy (Text)

p :: Text -> Bool
p = ("foo" `T.isPrefixOf`)
```

because `fromString` does not convert the lazy `String` into a lazy `Text` in a way that preserves the `undefined` unevaluated. I can test that the lazy version does work by writing a specialized test,

```
pTest :: Bool
pTest = p (T.fromChunks [ "foo", undefined ]) -- True
```

but I can't control how `fromString` chunks.

---

### Attempted solution:

I tried to write my own wrapper to control the chunking of `fromString`,

```
import qualified Data.Text      as T
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as LT

newtype LazyChunkyText = LazyChunkyText LT.Text deriving (Show)
instance IsString LazyChunkyText where
  fromString = LazyChunkyText . LT.fromChunks . map (T.pack . return)
```

But because `fromChunks` takes a `[T.Text]`, I need to `T.pack`.

Meaning my `[undefined]` gets evaluated.

Comment: I suppose, with `Data.Text.Lazy` I can't ever be sure how input is chunked and it may succeed for some streams and fail for others depending entirely on how it's chunked and regardless of the individual characters in the stream. So perhaps, as far as generalised tests go, it isn't a very good test after all.

Comment: The way that you've described the test, you are actually testing `fromString` rather than your predicate. Your original signature is `p :: IsString s => s -> Bool`, but you have separate implementations for `String` and `Text`?

Comment: @BobDalgleish: Thank you for pointing that out. I have separate implementations and one test suite, yes. I suppose I'll just have to succumb to the fact that I can't have a polymorphic test suite that lets me control how any particular `IsString s => s` is chunked. So I'll have to test each implementation separately.

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant, but note that `length ("foo" ++ [undefined]) == 4` while `length ("foo" ++ undefined) == undefined`. The `(T.fromChunks [ "foo", undefined ])` seems more similar to the latter than to the former.

Comment: @chi: Thanks; I meant to go with `T.fromChunks [ "foo", undefined ]`, but somehow tried both in the process.